# Bluetooth keyboard emulator on Windows, connected to iPhone

Tags: windows, bluetooth, iphone

The iPhone is sitting on my desk, on my right, in a dock. It has a Bluetooth keyboard attached, so I waste less time lifting it, typing and then putting it back in.

Is there a software on Windows which would emulate a bluetooth keyboard (the PC has bluetooth), and proxy key presses from the natural Windows keyboard to the iPhone? It would have to have a floating button or something similar to enable/disable proxying.

Answer (score 0):

this might work for you
It does not exactly run on windows, but it runs on a raspberry pi, that you can access via putty from your windows machine
http://github.com/rdubois440/btkbdemu

Good luck
Rene

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.